# Create excel attachment Object using VB or macros in a cell of Excel

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Please advise how can I create a Object in a cell of Excel using macros.
Please refer below Image:

[[image: Sample image]

I want to attach attachment like in image but using Script or any kind of formulas.

Thanks

Comment: Use the macro recorder, start a recording, add the image to the cell and when finished, stop it. You will find the macro containing the relevant steps to include the image in the "Show macro" section of the macro recorder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample I created using the method described in my comment:

**Excel macro**

```
'Select the cell that should contain the object
Range("B5").Select
'Add an object to the given cell
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\de12668\Documents\Zeichnung1.vsd", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _
    True, IconFileName:= _
    "C:\WINDOWS\Installer\{90140000-0057-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}\visicon.exe", _
    IconIndex:=0, IconLabel:="A sample"). _
    Select
```

---

**Update 1**

If the paths to the elements are provided in the first column, use this to add the appropriate links:

```
Dim myRange As range
Dim longLastRow As Long
Dim counter As Long

Set myRange = Worksheets(1).range("A1")
longLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, myRange.Column).End(xlUp).Row

For counter = 1 To longLastRow
  range("B" & counter).Select
  ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:= _
    range("A" & counter).Value, Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _
    True, IconFileName:= _
    range("A" & counter).Value, _
    IconIndex:=0, IconLabel:=""). _
    Select
Next
```

Comment: Thanks SaschaM78 for quick response, I have no knowledge about VB or macros can you guide me one more scenario I have list of link of  Document which is stored in my local system, So Can I create object for each link using Macros Please see image for reference http://imgur.com/a/zIik1  . I have a link in Column A and I want to create their Attachment in Column B, Kindly Suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Open VBA editor (Alt+F11)
   Tools->References-> Include "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" 
   Copy and paste the below code into excel VBA 
   Give the document path in A1 
   Run 
   Check the output whether it suits for you.

```
Sub CreateObject()
Dim shpGroup As Shape
Dim shpTextbox As Shape

Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim mfile As File
Dim mfolder As Folder
Dim mpath As String
Dim mrow As Integer

mpath = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value       'Path of the document files in the local system
mrow = 2

If fso.FolderExists(mpath) Then
    Set mfolder = fso.GetFolder(mpath)
    For Each mfile In mfolder.Files
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveSheet.Range("A" & mrow), _
        Address:=mfile.ShortPath, _
        TextToDisplay:=mfile.ShortPath
        ActiveSheet.Range("A" & mrow).Value = mfile.ShortPath
        Set shpGroup = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\learn\sun.jpg", msoFalse, msoTrue, 0, 0, 50, 50)       'give the Image path
        shpGroup.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        shpGroup.Left = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & mrow).Left
        shpGroup.Top = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & mrow).Top
        shpGroup.Width = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & mrow).Width
        shpGroup.Height = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & mrow).Height
        mrow = mrow + 1
    Next
End If

Set mfile = Nothing
Set mfolder = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```